# Chain and product rule for Hadamard product differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, jacobian, hadamard-product

(Asked a similar question before but deleted to add further detail)

Similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145673/product-rule-for-hadamard-product-differentation) question and a related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143897/hessian-of-quadratic-form-of-function-using-hadamard-and-frobenius-notation) question, how can I apply the chain and product rule to find the Jacobian of
$$
f_1(x) = (g(x) \odot A) \, h(x) \tag{$*$}
$$
and 
$$
f_2(x) = (g(x) \odot A \odot g(x))\, v \tag{$**$}
$$
for fixed vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, variable $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?
I'm having trouble computing the total derivative.

For an example of ($*$), I am trying to compute the total derivative for $f(x) = (-\sin(x) \odot M)\cos(x)$ with $y := -\sin(x)$, $z := \cos(x)$, and $w := Mz$ as:
\begin{align}
{\rm d} f(x) &= {\rm d}\{ (-\sin(x) \odot M)\cos(x) \} \\
&= {\rm d} \{(y \odot M)z\} = {\rm d} \{ y \odot (Mz) \} = {\rm d} \{y \odot w \} \\
&= y \odot {\rm d}w + {\rm d}y \odot w \\
&= y \odot (M J_{z} \,{\rm d}x) + J_y \, {\rm d}x \odot Mz \tag{$***$}
\end{align}
and Jacobian
$$
\frac{{\rm d} f(x)}{{\rm d}x} = y \odot (M J_{z}) + J_y \odot Mz
$$
but think I am messing something up. Is ($***$) correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate a function on a vector argument, as in your example, it must be applied element-wise.

The the differential of such a function is expressed, not in terms of the usual Jacobian, but as an element-wise version of the ordinary (scalar) derivative, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&y = \sin(x),\quad &z = \cos(x),\quad &w = Mz \cr
&dy = \cos(x)\odot dx,\quad &dz = -\sin(x)\odot dx,\quad &dw = M\,dz \cr
&dy = z\odot dx,\quad &dz = -y\odot dx \cr
}$$
where ($\odot$) denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Of course, diagonal matrices can be used to eliminate the Hadamard products.
$$\eqalign{
&Y = {\rm Diag}(y),\quad &Z = {\rm Diag}(z),\quad &W = {\rm Diag}(w) \cr
&dy = Z\,dx,\quad &dz = -Y\,dx,\quad &dw = -MY\,dx \cr
}$$
Now it becomes easy to calculate the differential and gradient of the function.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= -y\odot w \;= -w\odot y \cr
df &= -y\odot dw - w\odot dy \cr
   &= YMY\,dx - WZ\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 &= YMY - WZ \cr
}$$

Comment: Thx for your answer. Can you help me of my question? Thx a lot!   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451486/derivative-of-quadratic-equation-with-hadamard-product